# How do I find the corresponding address of an address I found on Windows on the same program that's running through WINE on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, wine

I want to read the value of a memory address of a program I found on Windows on Linux with the program running through WINE.

On Windows, the memory address 0x58FAAC either returns a 1 or a 0. On Linux when running the same program through WINE, that same address returns something completely different. It turns out the actual corresponding address on Linux is 0x98FAAC. However, it's not always a 4 bit difference. In other programs, the addresses seem completely different with no sort of pattern between them.

I don't want to have to research for every address manually on Linux as that could take ages. I've been told that I need to write an algorithm to find the corresponding address on Linux but I'm not sure what to do with that.

I've tried to apply the 4 bit difference I found with the first program to other programs but the other programs returned something completely random.

Comment: Include the smallest bit of code that could demonstrate what you are trying to achieve, otherwise it looks like you're on your way to be vote-closed due to lack of code. Read [mcve] to get a highlevel view of why code samples are important. Too long ago for me with `c` but can't you `printf` the addresses? Good luck.

Comment: Most executables these days are built with [address space layout randomization (ASLR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) enabled. Which means that, even if you run the same executable on the same computer twice, the same variable will land at different virtual addresses. This is meant precisely to prevent the kind of exploitation you envision.

Comment: @shellter there's no code for me to include because I'm not sure about what code to write. All I want to do is find the corresponding address of a Windows program on Linux.

In my C++ code, I use the process_vm_readv syscall to read memory addresses.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik are you talking about dynamic addresses? If so, the addresses I've found on Windows are specifically static addresses, they never change.

Comment: Static allocations appear in memory at a fixed offset from the load address of their corresponding module (i.e., DLL).  Compare the load addresses of the modules (e.g. with `GetModuleHandle(dll_name)`) and that will tell you how the variable addresses are related.